# export sheets to a new dynamic workbook and then export in PDF with same page break

Tags: vba, excel

here is my problem: I need to export a dynamic range to a sheet and then to a new workbook and then to PDF, my problem is that each time my pdf is creating the page break is not the same as the first sheet and i dont know what to do about it

please please help me And sorry in advance for the long code

BUT PLEASE I NEED HELP ;)

My code is the following

```
RR.Copy

        wsBS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
         'Define same Column idth and Row hight for copied range
        Dim r As Long, c As Long
        Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = RR
       Set TargetRange = wsBS.UsedRange

Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\User\Documents\Tests Salome\dailypdf.xlsx"

Dim wbto As Workbook: Set wbto = Workbooks("dailypdf.xlsx")
Dim sht As Worksheet

 wb.Activate
  For Each sht In Sheets
If sht.Name <> "BS" And sht.Name <> "Balance" Then
Else
sht.Copy Before:=wbto.Sheets(wbto.Sheets.Count)
    sht.PageSetup.PrintArea = UsedRange

End If
Debug.Print sht.Name
Next

Sheets("BS").Cells.Delete
 wbto.Activate
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 Dim wsto As Worksheet: Set wsto = wbto.Sheets("BS")

   With wsto.PageSetup
       .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = wsEUR.PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter
     .BlackAndWhite = wsEUR.PageSetup.BlackAndWhite
      .BottomMargin = wsEUR.PageSetup.BottomMargin
      .LeftMargin = wsEUR.PageSetup.LeftMargin
      .Orientation = wsEUR.PageSetup.Orientation
      .PaperSize = wsEUR.PageSetup.PaperSize
      .RightHeaderPicture.FileName = wsEUR.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture.FileName
       .RightMargin = wsEUR.PageSetup.RightMargin
      .TopMargin = wsEUR.PageSetup.TopMargin
       .Zoom = wsEUR.PageSetup.Zoom
     End With


            FileName = Create_PDF(Source:=wbto, _
                                      FixedFilePathName:=iFile, _
                                      OverwriteIfFileExist:=True, _
                                      OpenPDFAfterPublish:=False)
```

Thank you and sorry for this long code...

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean in “my problem is that each time my pdf is creating the page break is not as the first sheet”. Could you rephrase this sentence a bit, please?

Comment: It is not the same print layout, page break than the imported sheet

Comment: So, you want the `Worksheet.VPageBreaks` objects and `Worksheet.HPageBreaks` objects to have the same `.Location` values in both Workbooks?

Comment: Actually I would say your code isn't long enough because we have no idea what **RR**, **wsEUR**, **wsBS** or **wb** are (although it probably wont make too much difference here but would be good for clarification). It looks like you are setting the page on **`wsto`** but then using **`wbto`** to copy to PDF. Maybe that's where the issue is? without more code there is no way to be sure. Also, as a tip, please don't use `Sheets` as it makes code almost unreadable and causes confusion. You have qualified sheets, use them

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO that cover exporting page setup to pdf, you could do a search to help you with your problem. I would start a search "Export page setup to pdf correctly". You can also search Google.

Comment: @Chronocidal yes i want that when i copy past the sheet it has exactly the same location values and page break to be able to export my new workbook correctly

Comment: @Zac I past it to wbto because i want to insert a worksheet into the workbook as a new sheet

Comment: @Zac RR is the dynamic range in wsEUR I want to copy to a sheet(wsBS) and after to copy it to the new workbbok (wbto) to be able to export in pdf

Answer (score 0):

Code updated:

```vb
Sub CopyPageBreaks(Source As Worksheet, Dest As Worksheet)
    Dim BeforeCell As Range, lBreak As Long

    Dest.ResetAllPageBreaks 'Delete existing Page-Breaks

    'Horizontal Page Breaks
    For lBreak = 0 To Source.HPageBreaks.Count
        If lBreak > 0 Then
            Set BeforeCell = Source.HPageBreaks(lBreak).Location
            Dest.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Dest.Cells(BeforeCell.Row, BeforeCell.Column) 'Copy from source
        End If
    Next lBreak

    'Vertical Page Breaks
    For lBreak = 0 To Source.VPageBreaks.Count
        If lBreak > 0 Then
            Set BeforeCell = Source.VPageBreaks(lBreak).Location
            Dest.VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Dest.Cells(BeforeCell.Row, BeforeCell.Column) 'Copy from source
        End If
    Next lBreak

    Set BeforeCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

**{EDITED}** *Old code below*

---

Try something like this: (Currently unable to test)

```vb
Sub CopyPageBreaks(Source AS Worksheet, Dest As Worksheet)
    Dim pb AS Object, BeforeCell AS Range

    'Horizontal Page Breaks
    Dest.HPageBreaks.Delete 'Delete existing Page-Breaks
    For Each pb In Source.HPageBreaks
        Set BeforeCell = pb.Range
        Dest.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Dest.Cells(BeforeCell.Row, BeforeCell.Column) 'Copy from source
    Next pb

    'Vertical Page Breaks
    Dest.VPageBreaks.Delete 'Delete existing Page-Breaks
    For Each pb In Source.VPageBreaks
        Set BeforeCell = pb.Range
        Dest.VPageBreaks.Add Before:=Dest.Cells(BeforeCell.Row, BeforeCell.Column) 'Copy from source
    Next pb

    Set BeforeCell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont understand what source you are using? wbto is the destination excel file to which the sheets in "thisworkbook" are copied from

Comment: `Source` is the sheet you want to copy the Page Breaks from, `Dest` is the sheet you want to copy them to.  Although, I notice in your code above that you are setting the `PrintArea` for `sht` *after* you copy it from `wb` to `wbto`?  Perhaps swapping those lines over would be more help